# Flex, Flash Builder 4.6 Cs6 Copy and Paste doesn't work

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

I have a somewhat strange problem. This occurs only with the application on the Web server, and only in Chrome.

I have a SPARK textarea - `<s:TextArea>`.

For the first time I can copy and paste with both shortcut keys and the context menu.

But when I select another text, the latter copies correctly. But it pastes only the text selected first

I tried the property `mouseEnable = true` both in the Skin component as the component as it is within a popup `mxTitleWindow`. But it does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't found other information about the issue.

I found this bug report http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=154497, most likely is related with your issue.

Also I have seen many copy&paste issues with spark controls have you tried using a mx control instead?